# cant unset a $_SESSION variable when using a posted variable to remove

Tags: php, arrays, session

This page basically displays a table of a list of options from DB that a user can select, once selected the user is give the option to remove the selected option should they have made a mistake. I have taken out all of the unnecessary stuff to make it easier to follow.
I have tried every combination to get a session array element to unset and have pretty much given up.
I know the posted values are working ok as i have had them echoing back to the screen after submitting the form.
The array_search function does not seem to like a variable name, if I replace $ss_id with a physical value I can get it to unset ok.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php require_once('Connections/fs1.php'); 

    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
      session_start();
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['con29']))
    {
    $_SESSION['con29'] = array();
    }

    //db call to get con29 options
    $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sub_search_content") or die(mysql_error());

    $_SESSION['main_search_selected'] = 's7';
    $main_search_selected = $_SESSION['main_search_selected'];

    //setup the session variables depending on what was posted------------------

    if (isset($_POST['sub_search_content_id']))//add an option

        {
            $row_id_1 = $_POST['sub_search_content_id']; 
            array_push($_SESSION['con29'],$row_id_1);
        }

    if (isset($_POST['sub_search_content_id_remove']))
    {
        $ss_id = $_POST['sub_search_content_id_remove'];
        $key=array_search($ss_id,$_SESSION['con29']);
        if($key!==false) unset($_SESSION['con29'][$key]);
        //echo $ss_id;
        //echo $key;
    } 

    //print_r ($_SESSION['con29']);

    ?>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <?php


        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) 
            {


                    $sub_search_id = $_SESSION['con29'];

                    if($row[$main_search_selected] == 1)
                     {
                     $bgcolour = '#ffffff';
                     $select_row ='';
                     $select_row_2='';
                     }

                    elseif($row[$main_search_selected] == 2)
                     {

                         $id = $row['sub_search_content_id'];
                         $key = array_search($id, $sub_search_id);

                         if($key != '')
                                {
                                    $bgcolour = '#AFC137';
                                    $select_row = '<input name="submit" class="push_buttons" type="submit" value="Remove" />';
                                    $select_row_2 = '<input name="sub_search_content_id_remove" type="hidden" id="sub_search_content_id_remove" value="' . $row['sub_search_content_id'] .' " />';  
                                }
                         else
                                {
                                    $bgcolour = '#ffffff';
                                                                    $select_row = '<input name="submit" class="push_buttons" type="submit" value="select" />';
                                    $select_row_2 = '<input name="sub_search_content_id" type="hidden" id="sub_search_content_id" value="' . $row['sub_search_content_id'].'" />';  
                                }
                     }

                     elseif($row[$main_search_selected] == 3)
                     {

                                    $bgcolour = '#FF9900';
                                    $select_row = "Included";
                     }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


                            if($row[$main_search_selected] != 1)
                            { ?>

                                              <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $bgcolour;?>" >
                                                <form action="test1.php" method="POST" name="form1" id="form1"   >
                                                  <?php echo $select_row_2; ?>
                                                  <td width="60" height="25" align="center" valign="middle" class="top-edge-border-menu"><?php echo $row['sub_search_content_id']; ?></td>
                                                  <td align="center" valign="middle" class="top-and-right-edge-border-left"><?php echo $row['sub_title']; ?></td>
                                                  <td height="25" align="center" valign="middle" class="top-and-right-edge-border">price</td>
                                                  <td height="25" align="center" valign="middle" class="top-edge-border"><?php echo $select_row; ?></td>
                                                </form>
                                              </tr>
                                              <?php }
                     } ?>

                                            </table></td>
                                          </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
    <?php mysql_free_result($query1); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`value="' . $row['sub_search_content_id'] .' "`

Notice the trailing space there? When you're posting the ID back to the script to  remove it from the session, you're appending a space to the ID - this prevents `array_search` from finding it in your session.

Just change that line to:

```
$select_row_2 = '<input name="sub_search_content_id_remove" type="hidden" id="sub_search_content_id_remove" value="' . $row['sub_search_content_id'] . '" />';
```

Note - if you need to check a variable in detail, `var_dump()` is far superior to an `echo()` - it'll show you things like spaces and variable types.

Comment: hackenbecker - on a related note, probably best to tidy up user input, $ss_id = trim($_POST['sub_search_content_id_remove']); would probably have sidestepped this issue, best does some reaseach into sanitizing user input, eg if you expecting a number, strip out any none numeric characters and/or throw an error if you get something that is not a number

Comment: Thanks Sam, as you pointed out it was a dodgy trailing space, the var_dump showed it up instantly. All is now working as it should.